# Creating integration tests in Ember 2.16 that utilize window.confirm()?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, integration-testing

I am writing integration tests for an Ember 2.16 component and I am testing some user actions.

One of the user actions calls `window.confirm()`, where the user is asked if they are sure they want to delete an item before the item is deleted.

I want to test the functionality of this component, both with accepting and declining the confirm. The component action looks similar to this:

```
delete(id){
  if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){
    //do stuff
  } else {
    //do other stuff
  }
}
```

Inside my integration tests I am successfully clicking the button to bring up the prompt, but I am running into this error:

`[Testem] Calling window.confirm() in tests is disabled, because it causes testem to fail with browser disconnect error.`

How can I create an integration test that will bypass the `window.confirm()` functionality?

I have added in my component a way to bypass the confirm if the env is in "test" mode, but this does not really help as I am not testing the portion of code that relies on the `window.confirm()`.

I have looked around to see if there is a variable I can pass to the component to make the `window.confirm()` true/false, but have been unsuccessful.

How can I create a test that will test a component that calls `window.confirm()` inside an action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to save the original implementation of `window.confirm` and write your own implementation before your test, then restore the original implementation at the end of the test.

This is how I would do it:

```
// Watch out, this test is written with the latest ember-qunit syntax which might not be exactly what you have in your Ember 2.16 application
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupRenderingTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import { render } from 'ember-test-helpers';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

module('your component integration tests', function(hooks) {
  setupRenderingTest(hooks);

  test('clicking the OK confirm button', async function(assert) {
    // save the original window.confirm implementation
    const originalWindowConfirm = window.confirm;

    // simulate the OK button clicked
    window.confirm = function() { return true;}

    // ADD YOUR TEST AND ASSERTIONS HERE

    // restore the original window.confirm implementation
    window.confirm = originalWindowConfirm;
  });

});
```

Comment: This is fantastic! I was thinking I could "mock" it out, but didn't realize it was as easy as just replacing it with a function call inside my integration test. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I would stub `window.confirm()` in the test with a lib like [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.5.0/stubs/) where I expect it to be called so that:

1. hopefully that error message won't occur
2. I know `confirm()` is actually called by the code and does what I
   want it to do exactly (i.e., I can make it a simple fn)
3. it can be restored so the warning message will be logged in other
   tests (which is helpful)

According to the [testem code](https://github.com/testem/testem/blob/1960a16dd5de3611910f96a00b2b86da8fd39fdb/public/testem/testem_client.js#L438) it overwrites `window.confirm()` to print this warning message:

```
window.confirm = function() {
  throw new Error('[Testem] Calling window.confirm() in tests is disabled, because it causes testem to fail with browser disconnect error.');
};
```

So doing something like this in the test with sinon should work:

```
const confirm = sinon.stub(window, "confirm").callsFake(() => {
  // fake implementation here which overwrites the testem implementation
});

// rest of the test

confirm.restore(); // restores the testem implementation
```